# Undefined reference to a class in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a code::blocks project, called Test.cbp. It has three files, `main.cpp` in the `Test` directory, and `jAlg.cpp` and `jAlg.h`, both in the `jAlg` directory.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jAlg.h"

int main(){
    jVector bob;
    jMatrix ann;
    bob.display();
    return 0;
}
```

**jAlg.cpp** (summary)

```
class jMatrix{
    public:
        //The four entries of a 2x2 square matrix:
        //[a b]
        //[c d]
        double a, b, c, d;

        //Constructor
        jMatrix(double a_val = 1, double b_val = 0,
                double c_val = 0, double d_val = 1){
            a = a_val;
            b = b_val;
            c = c_val;
            d = d_val;
        }

        //Several other functions and operator overloads
};

class jVector{
    public:
        //The two entries of a 2D vector
        //[x]
        //[y]
        double x, y;

        //Constructor
        jVector(double x_val = 0,
                double y_val = 0){
            x = x_val;
            y = y_val;
        }

        //Several other functions and operator overloads
};

//Several other functions

//Matrix-vector multiplication
jVector operator* (jMatrix A, jVector v){
    jVector result;
    result.x = A.a*v.x + A.b*v.y;
    result.y = A.c*v.x + A.d*v.y;
    return result;
}

//More functions
```

**jAlg.h** (summary)

```
#ifndef JALG
#define JALG

double sqr(double x);

class jMatrix{
    public:
        double a, b, c, d;

        jMatrix(double a_val = 1, double b_val = 0,
                double c_val = 0, double d_val = 1);

        //more functions
};

class jVector{
    public:
        double x, y;

        jVector(double x_val = 0, double y_val = 0);

        //more functions
};

jVector operator* (jMatrix A, jVector v);

#endif
```

When I build and run the project, it behaves strangely. An error is raised saying `undefined reference to 'jMatrix::jMatrix(double,double,double,double)'`. However, there is no error related to the `jVector::jVector` constructor.

As a test I went to the `jAlg` files and commented out the `jVector operator* (jMatrix A, jVector v)` function and run the project again. This time, an error is raised for *both* `jMatrix::jMatrix` and `jVector::jVector`. For some reason, the presence of that function makes it okay to define vectors, but not matrices.

So here's my question: why does the presence of the function `jVector operator* (jMatrix A, jVector v)` make it okay to define `jVector`s? What can I do to make it possible to define `jMatrix` objects?

Answer (score 2):

In your `jAlg.cpp` file, you should only **define** your functions, don't **declare** everything again

```
jMatrix::jMatrix(double a_val, double b_val, double c_val, double d_val)
  : a{a_val}, b{b_val}, c{c_val}, d{d_val}
{ }

// ... define other jMatrix functions similarly

jVector::jVector(double x_val, double y_val)
  : x{x_val}, y{y_val}
{ }

// ... define other jVector functions

//Several other functions

jVector operator* (jMatrix A, jVector v)
{
    jVector result;
    result.x = A.a*v.x + A.b*v.y;
    result.y = A.c*v.x + A.d*v.y;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `jAlg.cpp` file you shouldn't redeclare your class, but just put definitions for the functions declared from `jAlg.h` (do so for the other class member functions analogous):

```
    jMatrix::jMatrix(double a_val, double b_val,
 // ^^^^^^^^^ Prefix class scope 
                 double c_val, double d_val)
: a(a_val), b(b_val), c(c_val), d(d_val) {}
```

Also use the member initializer list (as shown above).

The definition of the free function `jVector operator* (jMatrix A, jVector v);` is OK.